# How to add image to multiple buttons

Tags: ios

my application has 50 buttons.i want to add image to button programmatically to all buttons.

i declared buttons through outlet as

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *radiobtn1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *radiobtn2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *radiobtn3.
.
.
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *radiobtn50;
```

this is my array

```
NSMutableArray *allButtons;
allButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
allButtons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"radiobtn1", .....,@"radiobtn50",nil];
```

this is my logic

```
for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
{

 [self.allbuttons[i] setImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"radioButtonDisabled.png"]      forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}



but application is crashing with exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d4c'
```

Comment: change the "<=" into "<",

Answer (score 2):

In all button arrays you have string type value and `setImage` method for `UIButton` type object, not for `NSString` type. That's why your code is crashing.

Try this code to create multiple buttons and add to view -

```
float leftMargin = 20;
float topMargin  = 20;

for (int i=0 ; i<9; i++) {

UIButton *BtnObj           =   [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftMargin, topMargin,100,40)];
    [BtnObj setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [BtnObj setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [BtnObj addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:BtnObj];

    topMargin += 50;
}
```

And method to be called -

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"Button clicked");
}
```

Hope this will help.